# GWT widget not showing when I use a SplitLayoutPanel

Tags: java, gwt, widget

I'm new to GWT, and am struggling through my first Web page with it.

I've created 2 Composite Widgets - `ListWidget` and `MaintenanceWidget`. When I add them both to a `FlowPanel`, they both show up as they should. However, when I try to use a `SplitLayoutPanel`, depending on how I do it, either none of them show or only one of them shows.

Below is my code:

```
public MainPanel(){
    list = new ListWidget();
    maintenance = new MaintenanceWidget();
    panel = new SplitLayoutPanel();

    panel.addWest(list, 200);
    panel.addNorth(maintenance, 250);


    initWidget(panel);
}
```

In my entry point onModuleLoad() method, I create an instance of `MainPanel` and add it to the root pane.

With this code, I get a blank space in the west where the list should be, and the maintenance widget on the top with a horizontal splitter beneath it.

I've tried different configurations of the `panel.add****()` method, but nothing has gotten me the results I'm looking for.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Which widget receives that class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found some sample code [here](http://codingvilla.com/Forums/gwt-splitlayoutpanel-forums-topic-66.aspx) that used a method that I hadn't seen before.

My code now reads as follows:

```
public MainPanel(){
    list = new ListWidget();
    maintenance = new MaintenanceWidget();
    panel = new SplitLayoutPanel();

    panel.setPixelSize(500, 400);

    panel.addWest(list, 200);
    panel.add(maintenance);     
    initWidget(panel);
}
```

And now it works. Thanks for your help!

Comment: You shouldn't answer your question to add more details. Just edit your question.

Comment: I meant this to be an answer - now my code works. Edited to reflect that.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have a `doctype` declaration in your HTML template (for example, `<!doctype html>`), since `SplitLayoutPanel` requires browser to work in standards mode.

Comment: I do have one. Thanks, though.

Answer (score 0):

If not mistaken, SpliLayoutPanel must be attached to the body of the document.
Try something like:

```
public void onModuleLoad() {
    SplitLayoutPanel panel = new SplitLayoutPanel();

    panel.addWest(new Label("WEST"), 50);
    panel.addNorth(new Label("NORTH"), 50);
    panel.addEast(new Label("EAST"), 50);
    panel.addSouth(new Label("SOUTH"), 50);
    panel.add(new Label("CONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERECONTENT HERE"));

    RootLayoutPanel.get().add(panel); //This gets the body element and attaches itself to it, then adds panel.
}
```

Shouldn't be too hard to apply it to your code.